# jna CoCreateInstance

Tags: jna

am trying to create a link in windows 7 that has an icon. I am using the JNA library for this. I am having trouble with the call to CoCreateInstance. It returns error. First I am not sure if the GUID for IShellLink is the correct ( I am not a windows programer). Below is my code so far. Once I get the pointer to an IShellLink I would need to fill the paramaters for the link (target,icon, description, etc). I am modeling this call from the C code below found at this link (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11467/How-to-create-short-cuts-link-files). I know I could use mklink command for this but it does have an option to add an icon and description.

```
private void createLink(){
    Pointer reserved = null; //Must be null
    int dwCoInit = 0;

    HRESULT oleInitResult = Ole32.INSTANCE.CoInitializeEx(reserved,dwCoInit);
    if(oleInitResult.equals(W32Errors.S_OK)){
        GUID rclsid = Ole32Util.getGUIDFromString("{e82a2d71-5b2f-43a0-97b8-81be15854de8}"); //Shell object
        GUID riid = Ole32Util.getGUIDFromString("{000214EE-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"); //CLSID of the IShellLink object
        PointerByReference ppv = new PointerByReference();
        HRESULT oleCreateResult = Ole32.INSTANCE.CoCreateInstance(rclsid,null,ObjBase.CLSCTX_INPROC,riid,ppv);
        if(oleCreateResult.equals(W32Errors.S_OK)){

        }else{
            System.out.println("Failed to create link error "+oleCreateResult.intValue());
        }
    }
    Ole32.INSTANCE.CoUninitialize();
}
```

###################### C++ Sample code

```
/*
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Description: Creates the actual 'lnk' file (assumes COM has been initialized).
Parameters: pszTargetfile    - File name of the link's target, must be a non-empty string.
pszTargetargs    - Command line arguments passed to link's target, may be an empty string.
pszLinkfile      - File name of the actual link file, must be a non-empty string.
pszDescription   - Description of the linked item. If this is an empty string the description is not set.
iShowmode        - ShowWindow() constant for the link's target. Use one of:
                       1 (SW_SHOWNORMAL) = Normal window.
                       3 (SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED) = Maximized.
                       7 (SW_SHOWMINNOACTIVE) = Minimized.
                     If this is zero the showmode is not set.
pszCurdir        - Working directory of the active link. If this is an empty string the directory is not set.
pszIconfile      - File name of the icon file used for the link.  If this is an empty string the icon is not set.
iIconindex       - Index of the icon in the icon file. If this is < 0 the icon is not set.
Returns: HRESULT value >= 0 for success, < 0 for failure.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/
static HRESULT CreateShortCut(LPSTR pszTargetfile, LPSTR pszTargetargs, LPSTR pszLinkfile, LPSTR pszDescription, 
int iShowmode, LPSTR pszCurdir, LPSTR pszIconfile, int iIconindex) {
HRESULT       hRes;                  /* Returned COM result code */
IShellLink*   pShellLink;            /* IShellLink object pointer */
IPersistFile* pPersistFile;          /* IPersistFile object pointer */
WORD          wszLinkfile[MAX_PATH]; /* pszLinkfile as Unicode string */
int           iWideCharsWritten;     /* Number of wide characters written */
hRes = E_INVALIDARG;
if (
       (pszTargetfile != NULL) && (strlen(pszTargetfile) > 0) &&
       (pszTargetargs != NULL) &&
       (pszLinkfile != NULL) && (strlen(pszLinkfile) > 0) &&
       (pszDescription != NULL) && 
       (iShowmode >= 0) &&
       (pszCurdir != NULL) && 
       (pszIconfile != NULL) &&
       (iIconindex >= 0)
) {
    hRes = CoCreateInstance(&CLSID_ShellLink,     /* pre-defined CLSID of the IShellLink object */
                            NULL,                 /* pointer to parent interface if part of aggregate */
                            CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, /* caller and called code are in same process */
                            &IID_IShellLink,      /* pre-defined interface of the IShellLink object */
                            &pShellLink);         /* Returns a pointer to the IShellLink object */
    if (SUCCEEDED(hRes))
    {
      /* Set the fields in the IShellLink object */
      hRes = pShellLink->lpVtbl->SetPath(pShellLink, pszTargetfile);
      hRes = pShellLink->lpVtbl->SetArguments(pShellLink, pszTargetargs);
      if (strlen(pszDescription) > 0)
      {
        hRes = pShellLink->lpVtbl->SetDescription(pShellLink, pszDescription);
      }
      if (iShowmode > 0)
      {
        hRes = pShellLink->lpVtbl->SetShowCmd(pShellLink, iShowmode);
      }
      if (strlen(pszCurdir) > 0)
      {
        hRes = pShellLink->lpVtbl->SetWorkingDirectory(pShellLink, pszCurdir);
      }
      if (strlen(pszIconfile) > 0 && iIconindex >= 0)
      {
        hRes = pShellLink->lpVtbl->SetIconLocation(pShellLink, pszIconfile, iIconindex);
      }

      /* Use the IPersistFile object to save the shell link */
      hRes = pShellLink->lpVtbl->QueryInterface(pShellLink,        /* existing IShellLink object */
                                                &IID_IPersistFile, /* pre-defined interface of the IPersistFile object */
                                                &pPersistFile);    /* returns a pointer to the IPersistFile object */
      if (SUCCEEDED(hRes))
      {
        iWideCharsWritten = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, pszLinkfile, -1, wszLinkfile, MAX_PATH);
        hRes = pPersistFile->lpVtbl->Save(pPersistFile, wszLinkfile, TRUE);
        pPersistFile->lpVtbl->Release(pPersistFile);
      }
      pShellLink->lpVtbl->Release(pShellLink);
    }

  }
  return (hRes);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turn out to be very simple. So If you hit this page you probably will save couple days by following this instructions:
Generate the  mappings for the shell32.dll per instructions in the com4j site:
http://com4j.java.net/tutorial.html
Then just call the following to create the icons. It is very simple once you know.

```
IWshShell3 shellLink = ClassFactory.createWshShell();
Com4jObject obj =  shellLink.createShortcut(linkPath.getAbsolutePath());
IWshShortcut link = obj.queryInterface(IWshShortcut.class);
link.workingDirectory(desktopPath.getAbsolutePath());
link.description("My Link");
link.arguments(" Hello ");
link.iconLocation(iconPath.getAbsolutePath());
link.targetPath(javawsPath.getAbsolutePath());
link.setName("Test Link");
link.save();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the called to CoCreateInstance by changing the GUID. Below is the code and it returns OK. But now that I got the pointer I am not sure how to set the parameters I need (link name, target name, desc, icon). Anybody has any suggestions?

```
GUID rclsid = Ole32Util.getGUIDFromString("{00021401-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"); //CLSID_ShellLink 
if (W32Errors.FAILED(hr.intValue())) { 
    Ole32.INSTANCE.CoUninitialize(); 
    throw new Exception("Shell Object GUID failed."); 
}       
GUID riid = Ole32Util.getGUIDFromString("{000214EE-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"); //CLSID of the IShellLink object
PointerByReference ppv = new PointerByReference();
hr = Ole32.INSTANCE.CoCreateInstance(rclsid,null,WTypes.CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER,riid,ppv);
if(hr.equals(W32Errors.S_OK)){
    Pointer type = ppv.getValue();

}else{
    System.out.println("Failed to create link error "+hr.intValue());
}
```

Comment: There is currently some work being done by [Tobias Wolf](https://github.com/wolftobias) to facilitate [COM operations via JNA](https://github.com/wolftobias/jna) that will soon be merged.  Alternatively, [com4j](http://com4j.java.net) and [jacob](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jacob-project/) are projects provide some aids to Java/COM integration.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I was going to the process of looking at the com object with the MS Visual Dev tools to create the function table. I had seen the project talked about but I was trying to avoid to learn one more jar but there is no better way than with com4j project. Thanks for pointing that to me.

Comment: I tried using the com4j api. I generated the stub code using command: java -jar tlbimp.jar -o wsh -p com.test.shell %SYSTEMROOT%\System32\shell32.dll. Unfortunatelly it creates the interface IShellLinkDual which it should work but there is no method in the ClassFactory to called. There seems to be something wrong with the GUID for the class id of this interface. Otherwise it would have worked nice.

Comment: Yeah the stubs that com4j generates for Shell32.dll seem to be very incomplete